# How to create a nested pie chart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pie-chart

I have a dataframe as such

```
error_code, num_errors, event_type
404,78,GET
403,8,GET
504,54,POST
304,67,UP
```

I would like to create a nested ie chart where the first layer would show the breakdown (each slice represents fraction of num_errors) with respect to `error_code` column.
The next layer would show the breakdown with respect to `event_type` column

Here is what i tried so far

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.pie(pdfrt.groupby('error_code')['num_errors'].sum(),radius=1,  
       labels=pdfrt['error_code'].values,
       autopct='%1.0f%%',
       wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5, edgecolor='w'))

ax.pie(pdfrt['num_errors'].values, labels=pdfrt['event_type'].values,radius=1-0.5, autopct='%1.0f%%',
       wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5, edgecolor='w'))

ax.set_title('Errors Count')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

but i get error

`ValueError: 'label' must be of length 'x'`

at

```
ax.pie(pdfrt.groupby('error_code')['num_errors'].sum(),radius=1,  
           labels=pdfrt['error_code'].values,
           autopct='%1.0f%%',
           wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5, edgecolor='w'))
```

what am i doing wrong? note that i am able to create a single level pie chart as

```
ax.pie(pdfrt['num_errors'].values, labels=pdfrt['event_type'].values,radius=1-0.5, autopct='%1.0f%%',
           wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5, edgecolor='w'))
```

or even

```
ax.pie(pdfrt['num_errors'].values, labels=pdfrt['error_code'].values,radius=1-0.5, autopct='%1.0f%%',
           wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5, edgecolor='w'))
```

the problem is how do i combine the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pdfrt.groupby('error_code')['num_errors'].sum()
```

&

```
labels=pdfrt['error_code'].values
```

Unlike your example, the length of the output of the above two codes in the actual dataset is different()

So modify like below

```
labels=pdfrt['error_code'].values
```

->

```
labels=pdfrt.groupby('error_code')['num_errors'].sum().index
```

**full Code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.pie(pdfrt.groupby('error_code')['num_errors'].sum(),radius=1,  
       labels=pdfrt.groupby('error_code')['num_errors'].sum().index, autopct='%1.0f%%',
       wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5, edgecolor='w'))



ax.pie(pdfrt['num_errors'], labels=pdfrt['event_type'], radius=1-0.5, autopct='%1.0f%%',
       wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5, edgecolor='w')) # also removed unnecessary values ​​attribute

ax.set_title('Errors Count')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```